# WCF Service with Castle Windsor dependency injection hosted in IIS

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, castle-windsor

I am making my first attempt at creating a WCF service, to be hosted on a server with IIS. The service will have a dependency on a separate class to retrieve data from a SQL database, so am attempting to keep this loosely coupled through IoC using Castle Windsor.

Here are the various aspects of the WCF service (apologies in advance to any C#ers out there but I'm a VB man!):

**Service Contract**

```
<ServiceContract()> _
Public Interface IGetRiskDataService

    <OperationContract()>
    Function GetRisksByInsuredOpenBoxID(ByVal openBoxID As String) As List(Of Risk)

End Interface
```

**Risk** is my own class used to contain the data retrieved from the database.

**Implementation of service contract**

```
Public Class GetRiskDataService : Implements IGetRiskDataService

    Private _rep As IDataWarehouseRepository

    Public Sub New(ByVal rep As IDataWarehouseRepository)
        _rep = rep
    End Sub

    Public Function GetRisksByInsuredOpenBoxID(openBoxID As String) As List(Of Risk) Implements IGetRiskDataService.GetRisksByInsuredOpenBoxID
        Return _rep.GetRisksByInsuredOpenBoxID(CType(openBoxID, Integer))
    End Function
End Class
```

As you can see, I am injecting the class used to get the data from the SQL database into the constructor of the WCF service.

**svc file**

```
<% @ServiceHost Service="DataWarehouseWCFService.GetRiskDataService" Factory="Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.DefaultServiceHostFactory, Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration" %>
```

**App.config file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DataWarehouseWCFService.GetRiskDataServiceBehavior"
    name="DataWarehouseWCFService.GetRiskDataService">
        <!--<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="DataWarehouseWCFService.IGetRiskDataService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>-->
    <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
    <endpoint address="../GetRiskDataService.svc"
       binding="webHttpBinding"
       contract="DataWarehouseWCFService.IGetRiskDataService"
       behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/DataWarehouseWCFService/GetRiskDataService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DataWarehouseWCFService.GetRiskDataServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehaviour">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

I think everything here is OK, except maybe the App.config file which I have largely left alone.

I then created a basic ASP.Net Web application which would reside on the IIS server to host the service. In the web application, the global.asax file looks like this:

```
Private _container As IWindsorContainer
Private _sqlConnection As String = "Data Source=[Server Name];Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=[Database Name];"

Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when the application is started

    _container = New WindsorContainer

    _container.AddFacility(Of WcfFacility).Register(Component.For(Of IDataWarehouseRepository).ImplementedBy(Of SQLDataWarehouseRepository).DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("connect", _sqlConnection)), _
                                                    Component.For(Of IGetRiskDataService).ImplementedBy(Of GetRiskDataService))

End Sub
```

So here I register the service with Castle Windsor, including the dependency on the SQL data retrieval class. Hopefully so far, so good...

I have deployed and installed this hosting application on the IIS Server with no problems.

So all that remains is to consume the service in a client application, which is where I come unstuck. I have an MVC4 application where I wish to use the web service to display data in a View. I already use Castle Windsor in this application to register other dependencies, so all the Castle Windsor infrastructure required already exists. Therefore all I thought I needed was an Installer for the web service. My attempt at this is below:

```
Public Class DataWarehouseWebServicesInstaller : Implements IWindsorInstaller

Private Const _getRiskDataServiceEndpoint As String = "http://[Server Name].[Domain Name]/Data Warehouse Web Services/GetRiskDataService.svc"

Public Sub Install(container As Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer, store As Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.IConfigurationStore) Implements Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.IWindsorInstaller.Install
    'Data Warehouse Web Services
    container.Register(Component.For(Of IEndpointBehavior).ImplementedBy(Of WebHttpBehavior))
    container.AddFacility(Of WcfFacility).Register( _
                                            Component.For(Of IGetRiskDataService).AsWcfClient( _
                                                New DefaultClientModel( _
                                                    WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(New WebHttpBinding).At(_getRiskDataServiceEndpoint) _
                                                    ) _
                                                ) _
                                            )
End Sub
End Class
```

Finally I added some test code to a Controller to see if could get the WCF service to work:

```
    Public Sub New(ByVal ash As IGetRiskDataService)
        Dim lozza = ash.GetRisksByInsuredOpenBoxID(100005859)
        For Each lianne As Risk In lozza
            Dim neil As Date = lianne.ExpiryDate.CalendarDate
        Next
    End Sub
```

On testing this I get the following error:

```
{"The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.."}. The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
```

This is where I am lost. I have researched issues of client and service bindings being mismatched, but unfortunately almost every answer refers to these bindings being specified in the app.config file, which I do not do as I am relying on Castle Windsor to handle most of this, and any configurations I do make I want to do in code. So for example, in my Installer code I register an endpoint with WebHttpBinding.

I feel I am close with this but have hit the proverbial brick wall. Any help would be gladly appreciated. Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide you with.

Many thanks,

Ash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is a fairly generic error when there is something mis-configured in your service. The service is not running at all properly and returning a standard wcf html error page - the client is expecting a soap response but all its getting is the error html.

To work out whats actually wrong you should navigate to your service in your browser

```
http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/DataWarehouseWCFService/GetRiskDataService/GetRiskDataService.svc
```

the error message displayed here will be much more descriptive.

Just looking over what you have posted so far, it could be related to...

- Is your Risk class marked up as a DataContract with the DataMember attributes?
- You probably dont need the address="../GetRiskDataService.svc" part on your endpoint address

Comment: Hello Matt, thanks for your reply. I did not have my Risk Class marked with those attributes, because I read somewhere that for simple POCO classes these would be serialized correctly without the attributes. Adding them made no difference. I also took out the endpoint address attribute from my app.config file. Again no luck.

Comment: The URL you suggested looks very different to the one I use. Just pasting your URL into the browser doesn't work. May I ask how you came up with that URL? Thanks so much, Ash.

Comment: In your app.config for your service you have a base address specified as "http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/DataWarehouseWCFService/GetRiskDataService/" - that plus you svc file name GetRiskDataService.svc

Comment: Try adding "<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />" underneath your other endpoint. Getting a response in the browser is a good first step to egtting this working. Also, what url are you using?

Comment: That base address was added by the Visual Studio designer - nothing to do with me! I will add the metadata back in. The URL I am using is of the form http://[Server Name].[Domain Name]/Data Warehouse Web Services/GetRiskDataService.svc

Comment: Hello Matt, I can't seem to get the metadata working. I added the correct endpoint back in but I am still getting a message saying metadata is disabled. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried http://[Server Name].[Domain Name]:[PortNumber]/Data Warehouse Web Services/GetRiskDataService.svc

Comment: Tried it with Port 80 (as per the IIS configuration for http bindings) and still no metadata.

Comment: Good news Matt!! Got the metadata working, so now see the page for my service. What next? Thanks, Ash

Comment: Make sure you've updated the endpoint in your client config to match the url. Try again and update your question with the error message

Comment: Matt, I've got it working!! Embarassingly, the reason was that the SQL stored procedure the service uses had been removed from the database (I have no idea how). Once I put it back everything worked perfectly. Thank you for all your help and I'll mark your answer as correct because you still helped me with the metadata and diagnosis. Thanks again, Ash

Comment: Thanks Ash, glad its sorted